# Laravel Eloquent - Return array of values from conditional hasMany relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, has-many

I am rather new to PHP, and this has really thrown me. I know I could do this with raw SQL, but I'd rather do it the right way.

I have the relationships set up, and they are working fine.

I have a table of houses, I want to get the names of all the people in those houses if the houses have a red roof, but only if the person has brown shoes.

```
    Houses::with('people')
        ->whereHas('people', function($q){
            $q->where('shoes', 'brown');
        })->where('roof','red')->get()
```

This is as far as I have gotten.

House Table:

```
+----+--------+
| id | roof   |
+----+--------+
|  1 | red    |
|  2 | blue   |
|  3 | red    |
+----+--------+
```

People table

```
+----+----------+-------+-------+
| id | house_id | shoes | name  |
+----+----------+-------+-------+
|  1 |        1 | brown | paul  |
|  2 |        1 | brown | susie |
|  3 |        2 | red   | bob   |
|  4 |        2 | brown | kate  |
|  5 |        3 | brown | frank |
+----+----------+-------+-------+
```

My wanted output is an array of people names like this:

```
[paul, susie, frank]
```

I feel like I have been beating my head against a wall all day

Comment: Hello! Thanks for the question - I can't see your `colour` column: `where('colour','red)`

Comment: Sorry, i will edit the question. It should be where('roof', 'red')

Comment: you have to check first roof then check shoes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are requesting people, you are better off starting from your `People` Model.

Please note that the `whereHas` expects the table name, and not the relation in the first argument.

```
    $people = People::where('shoes', 'brown')
        ->whereHas('houses', function ($query) {
            $query->where('roof', 'red');
    })->get();
```

Comment: Thankyou. I did consider doing it that way, but the 'people' table is almost fifty times the size of the houses table, so was trying to go the other way.

Comment: You will still have to run queries on both so the order wont matter. Efficient indexing would help speed up the queries.

Comment: Please consider accepting the solution so it can help others as well 